# Unable to collect Given password in shell command line argument as same as i entered

Tags: linux, bash, shell, automation

```
./test.sh -p Admin$2014
```

Here `-p` specifies a flag for password and my password is `Admin$2014`

In my script i am collecting `$2` in to a Variable called as PASSWORD. i.e.

```
PASSWORD="$2"
```

while i am reading the same using echo command

```
echo  "Password: $PASSWORD"
```

Output:

```
Password: Admin014
```

=====

Some one please tell me how to make my command line arguments are like string constants.

==============

Working Cases are:
Case1:

```
./test.sh -p 'Admin$2014'
```

Case2:

```
./test.sh -p Admin\$2014
```

In above two cases i am able to get correct result, but i don't want to enter any other letters in password.

Comment: strings have to be entered by quotes otherwise they are may interpreted as commands. there are few more problematic passwords

Answer (score 1):

You aren't "entering any other letters in [the] password" when you quote or escape the string.

You cannot get the shell to magically know that you don't want it to interpret shell metacharacters in *that* argument specifically the way you want. (That's what quoting and escaping are for.)

Your best solution, other than to require quoting, is simply not to use a command line argument for your script and instead to have the script prompt for the password using `read -rsp 'Password: ' PASSWORD` inside the script.

The argument read by `read` will not be subject to shell evalution/expansion/etc. and so shell metacharacters will not cause problems.

Using `-r` will disable backslash escapes in the read input as well.

Using `-s` will cause the input not to be echoed to screen (like most password prompts).

Using `read` will also have the side-effect of keeping your password from being available in the output of `ps` and the like while your script is running.

Comment: But my requirement is with -P flag i need to enter Password from command line only.
As first argument is -P and second one must be Password(Admin$2011).

Can any one give me how to achieve this...

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @KishoreChv The only way to do what you want is to quote the argument. That's it. The only alternative which doesn't require quoting is to use `read` (with whichever flags you find appropriate.